# BATCH : DO IF NOT EXIST (RECURSIVELY)

Tags: csv, batch-processing, not-exists

Here is my problem. I have a text file [list_csv.txt] of all the CSV of ../DIRECTORY/DATE(S)/CSV which have been recursively generated using this little script:

```
FOR /r %%A IN (*.csv) DO ECHO %%~nxA >> list_csv.txt
```

There is only one name.csv per line in the text file.

Now I want to generate an updated list using something like this:

```
FOR /r %%B IN (*.csv) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=1" %%C IN (list_csv.txt) DO IF NOT EXIST %%~nxB (
       ECHO %%~nxB >> Updated_list_csv.txt
    )
)
```

This code doesnt works the way I want it to, obviously too many test.. so how could I go through folders recursively and see if new CSVs have been dumped?

Thanks